# How to calculate only decrease or increase part of the sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

How to calculate only decrease or increase part of the sum?
For example:

| ID | Month | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | January 2019 | 100 |
| 2 | January 2019 | 120 |
| 3 | January 2019 | 90 |
| 4 | January 2019 | 60 |
| 1 | January 2020 | 150 |
| 2 | January 2020 | 90 |
| 3 | January 2020 | 130 |
| 4 | January 2020 | 40 |

| Value increased | Value decreased |
| --- | --- |
| 90 | 50 |

Of Course in real data file there is thousands of different ID.

Tried formula in pivot table:

`=IF(FILTER(Value, Month = "January 2019") > FILTER(Value, Month = "January 2020"), FILTER(Value, Data = "January 2019")-FILTER(Value, Data = "January 2020"), FILTER(Value, Data = "January 2020")-FILTER(Value, Data = "January 2019"))`

Moving variable in pivot table.
The closest I got was putting IDs in rows, dates in columns and 'Difference from' date, but I couldn't remove the positive/negative values.

Answer (score 1):

Using LET:

Positive:

```
=LET(
    ID,A2:A9,
    m,B2:B9,
    v,C2:C9,
    u,UNIQUE(ID),
    vl,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(z,SUMIFS(v,ID,z,m,"January 2020")-SUMIFS(v,ID,z,m,"January 2019"))),
    ABS(SUM(FILTER(vl,vl>0))))
```

Negative:

```
=LET(
    ID,A2:A9,
    m,B2:B9,
    v,C2:C9,
    u,UNIQUE(ID),
    vl,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(z,SUMIFS(v,ID,z,m,"January 2020")-SUMIFS(v,ID,z,m,"January 2019"))),
    ABS(SUM(FILTER(vl,vl<0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Sir you could have returned the value in one formula only from this `ABS(SUM(FILTER(vl,vl>0)))` to this `HSTACK(ABS(SUM(FILTER(vl,vl>0))),ABS(SUM(FILTER(vl,vl<0)))))`

Comment: Yeah, I will let them do that if they want.  I wanted to show the difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
=LET(i,A2:A9,m,B2:B9,v,C2:C9,
a,WRAPROWS(SORTBY(v,i,,m,),2),
     d,DROP(a,,1),
     t,TAKE(a,,1),
     VSTACK("Value "&{"In","De"}&"creased",
            HSTACK(SUM(IF(t<d,d-t,0)),
                   SUM(IF(t>d,d-t,0)))))
```

[image]

Caveat: This formula assumes there's two values for each ID, one for the old and one for the new year. If it doesn't, the calculation will be off.

Comment: Ah looks like we were thinking in the same way =) Just posted a comment with `WRAPCOLS()` in Scott Sir post

Comment: Does this assume 4 unique ids? and does it assume it is sorted?  May want to explain what needs to change in the formula to deal with `Of Course in real data file there is thousands of different ID.`

Comment: I read it as being the quarters (4 per year), but with that comment I doubt that is a good assumption. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ScottCraner since he's comparing 2 years, I changed it from wraprows to wrapcols (sorted by ID, then Month). This solution will only work if all ID's have 2 values, otherwise it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

### Split Increase and Decrease

- This assumes that each month-year has the same IDs.
- The data need not be sorted (the first line sorts it in the way shown in the screenshot: by ID then by month).

```
=LET(data,A2:C21,icol,1,mcol,2,vcol,3,
    ds,SORT(data,HSTACK(icol,mcol),1),
    m,CHOOSECOLS(ds,mcol),
    mu,UNIQUE(m),
    ms,DROP(mu,-1),
    me,DROP(mu,1),
    v,CHOOSECOLS(ds,vcol),
    dr,DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(ms)),LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(
        vw,WRAPROWS(FILTER(v,(m=INDEX(ms,r))+(m=INDEX(me,r))),2),
        cs,CHOOSECOLS(vw,1)-CHOOSECOLS(vw,2),
    VSTACK(rr,HSTACK(SUM(IF(cs>0,cs,)),SUM(IF(cs<0,ABS(cs),))))))),1),
HSTACK(ms,me,dr))
```

[image]